# Consolidating All AWS Member Account Health Notifications and sending it to SNS endpoint using Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, health-monitoring, aws-organizations

I am trying to consolidate all health events of member accounts in AWS Organization and steer them to AWS Org Account. This was done using AWS Feature of Aggregating all events and enabling Organizational View for AWS Health.

Now that health events are coming through to AWS Org account and I have an organizational view from one account, I want to send those notifications to our monitoring tool using the email endpoint.

I have tried to depict a crude design below:

[image: Consolidating AWS Health Events]

I need some pointers on how to forward the aggregated notifications received from member accounts to a lambda function (Python) whenever a new health notification is received from a member account to AWS Org Account.

Currently, its only working for host account i.e. AWS Org account in this case.

Thanks in advance.